# FullCalendar TimelineYear view - Start Date

Tags: fullcalendar

Racking my brain trying to get the TimelineYear view to start at a certain date. I have the Scheduler Plugin.

E.g.
https://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-scheduler-1.7.1/demos/scale.html

When you click on the Year button, it starts in Jan. Using Start Date, Visable Range, nothing works. Id like Todays date to be viewable automatically without having to scroll across to September as an example.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Show us your code.  What have you tried?
  Please visit the help centre and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: AFAIK you can't unfortunately. You'd have to make the viewport wide enough to see everything at once (unlikely in this case!). But think about the use case. If the user wants to focus on today (that example BTW is set up to go to a specific date, but you don't have to have that, it will default to today when it loads) then they can easily use one of the other views. If they want to see the whole year, then their focus is clearly not on the current day...so why do you need to do this? Sometimes features are missing because they're not really necessary.

Comment: You _could_ however make a view with a smaller custom date range, e.g. using visibleRange as you mentioned. Or if you _really_ want this exact feature, you can try modifying fullcalendar.js yourself to implement it, and submit it as a patch to the maintainer for integration into the product, or you can make a feature request to them and wait. This is done via the GitHub page I believe. P.S. There's no calendar option called "start date" so I don't know where you got the idea you could use that to configure anything (as you mention in the question)?